# Expected value of $XY$ and $X^2Y^2$ for discrete and not independent random variables

Tags: statistics, expected-value, independence

I am aware that for a discrete random variable X with equally likely outcomes, we have:

$$E[X] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

Can we make the claim that for two not independent discrete random variables X and Y with equally likely outcomes, the following hold true:

$$E[XY] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$$ and

$$E[X^2Y^2] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 y_i^2$$

If not, can you please someone provide some guidelines to compute $E[XY]$ and $E[X^2Y^2]$?

Comment: No, they are both wrong. The right hand sides of your equations depend on the way $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s are arranged but left side is independent  of the way $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s are arranged .

Comment: Are the $x_i$ and $y_i$ samples or the whole population?  If they are the population then your expressions are unlikely to be correct (try an example with $n=2$).  If they are random samples (with replacement) and you take expectations of the right hand sides, then they would be correct

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I do not have independence, i.e. $E[XY] \neq E[X] E[Y]$.

Comment: @Thoth You will need to know *how* they are dependent.  Some way to describe the joint probability distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear.  What do the $x_i$ and $y_i$ represent?

The only reasonable interpretation I can make is that $X$ is a random variable with discrete support $\mathcal X = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ such that for each $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, $$\Pr[X = x_i] = \frac{1}{n};$$ that is to say, $X$ is discrete uniform on the set $\mathcal X$; similarly, $Y$ is discrete uniform on the set $\mathcal Y = \{y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n\}$.  Then $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \Pr[X = x_i] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i,$$ as you claimed; but
$$\operatorname{E}[XY] = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x_i y_j \Pr[(X = x_i) \cap (Y = y_j)] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x_i y_j = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \sum_{j=1}^n y_j,$$ where $\overset{\text{ind}}{=}$ requires that $X$ and $Y$ be independent.  If not, then you would need to know the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, because uniformity of the marginal probabilities is not sufficient to imply independence (e.g., there could be perfect association).

---

So for example, suppose $\mathcal X = \{1, 3, 5, 7\}$ and $\mathcal Y = \{2, 4, 6, 8\}$, with $n = 4$, and each of $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed on these sets, respectively.  Then in the case of independence, $\Pr[(X = 1) \cap (Y = 2)] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \Pr[X = 1]\Pr[Y = 2] = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{16}$, but if for example $$Y = X + 1,$$ then $\Pr[(X = 1) \cap (Y = 2)] = \frac{1}{4}$, not $\frac{1}{16}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So If they are independent, $E[X^2Y^2] = \frac{1}{n^4}\sum_{i,j} x_i^2 y_j^2$ ?

Comment: @Thoth No.  $$\operatorname{E}[X^2 Y^2] = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \sum_{j=1}^n y_j^2.$$

Comment: Ok now thinks are more clear.